# Null check operator used on a null value error in widgets library

Tags: flutter, widget, null-check

this happened after I insert google map code
I'm creating a tracking app which will use the google map to display the tracked location

the error is shown as bellow

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building busNearby(dirty, state: _busNearbyState#460c7):
Null check operator used on a null value

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('TRACKER'),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber[500],
    ),
    body:  Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: [
            const HoveringWidget(),
            GoogleMap(
              initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
                  target: _utm,
                  zoom: 13),
              markers: {
                Marker(
                    markerId: MarkerId("_currentLocation"),
                    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
                    position: _currentP!),
                Marker(
                    markerId: MarkerId("_sourceLocation"),
                    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
                    position: _utm),
                Marker(
                    markerId: MarkerId("_destinationLoaction"),
                    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
                    position: _paradigm)
              },

            ),

          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: Can you share the content of your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can assume that `_currentP` is not initialized before you use it.
You can either use your preferred state manager or FutureBuilder to resolve this issue.

FutureBuilder Example:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: getCurrentP(),
    builder: ((context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const SizedBox();
      }

      return Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId("_currentLocation"),
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
          position: snapshot.data!);
    }));
```

Comment: it did fix the error thank you but I still donno why the google maps wont show up